# How to calculate Edit distance between two string of integers in java?

Tags: java

Is there any library to calculate the edit distance between two integer strings in java?

Comment: Most likely. There are libraries for thousands of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Apache Commons Text, there is the apache.commons.text.similarity namespace.  There are multiple definitions of "distance", but the [Levenshtein Distance](https://commons.apache.org/sandbox/commons-text/jacoco/org.apache.commons.text.similarity/LevenshteinDistance.html) is a good place to start.

Comment: Please don't encourage people to think StackOverflow is a human powered search engine.

Comment: Kayaman: I hear what you're saying.  On the other hand, It seems pretty rare to me that I see a question on StackOverflow that could not be answered through Google - if you know the right thing to search for.  Levenshtein Distance is an uncommon enough term that it is reasonable to suppose that a reasonably capable person might not know to search for it.

Comment: No, he seemed to know the term [Edit Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance). They really should have "basics of Googling" in schools these days.